# Nagios alert to a file

Tags: nagios

Is there any way to store Nagios alert to a file.

We have a private network and Nagios is configured there to monitor 100+ servers. Since there is no mail server in this network default nagios alert configuration is not possible. If we can able to store the Nagios alert to a file, by using one of our software alerting can be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It can be set up to alert you on anything.

I'm pretty sure you'd need to setup a command definition with something like the following and then use it as your notification command.

pseudocode:

```
define command {
    command_name alert_to_file
    command_line echo " $hostname is down since $time" >> /path/to/file
}
```

Comment: How I can use this as notification command. 
can you provide more detailed info.